# Why does 8 != 8.000 when the fields are decimal/double?

Tags: orbeon, xforms

I have a couple controls in my XForm, lets just call them x and y.

The value of x is 8; the value of y is 8.000
I set the constraint to: *$x = $y*

Apparently, XForms doesn't consider these values to be equal, regardless of whether the data type is double or decimal.

One solution is to do: *$x - $y = 0*

But will XForms have rounding errors?
So now it needs to be something like: *abs($x - $y) < 0.00001*

Is there an absolute value function?

This just seems messy for something that should be simple. Is there any easier way to get an XForm to consider 8 = 8.000?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that language, but in pseudocode:

Set some really small $epsilon := .00001

Then check if $x - $y < $epsilon

This obviously won't catch all rounding errors, but as long as your application isn't doing anything too important (and if it is you shouldn't be using floats anyway) this should consider 8 and 8.000 the same.

Edit: I notice you've already come up with this answer, so disregard this :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast the value first before you compare it.

```
<xforms:input
  ref="foo"
  xxforms:format="format-number(xs:integer(.), '###,##0')"/>
```

See [this link](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xforms-other-extensions#TOC-The-xxforms%3aformat-attribute) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

number() solves the problem and defining datatypes is also not required. See the below simple code.

```
<xhtml:html xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:xxforms="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xforms"
    xmlns:xforms="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms">

    <xhtml:head>
      <xhtml:title>Xforms</xhtml:title>

      <xforms:model>

        <xforms:instance id="main-instance">
            <form>
                <nodes>
                    <x>8</x>
                    <y>8.00</y>
                </nodes>
            </form>
        </xforms:instance>

        <xforms:bind id="x" nodeset="instance('main-instance')/nodes/x" />

        <xforms:bind id="y" nodeset="instance('main-instance')/nodes/y" />

      </xforms:model>

    </xhtml:head>

    <xhtml:body>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    X is 
                    <xforms:output bind="x">
                        <xforms:alert>Invalid</xforms:alert>
                    </xforms:output>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Y is
                    <xforms:output bind="y">
                        <xforms:alert>Invalid</xforms:alert>
                    </xforms:output>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <strong>X = Y ? </strong>
                    <xforms:output value="instance('main-instance')/nodes/x = instance('main-instance')/nodes/y">
                        <xforms:alert>Invalid</xforms:alert>
                    </xforms:output>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <strong>(using number function) X = Y ? </strong>
                    <xforms:output value="number(instance('main-instance')/nodes/x) = number(instance('main-instance')/nodes/y)">
                        <xforms:alert>Invalid</xforms:alert>
                    </xforms:output>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </xhtml:body>

</xhtml:html>
```

However when we give datatype as xforms:decimal to both the nodes and without using number function, it will not work (condition return false).